# Excel VBA - Filter and copy in multiple

Tags: vba, excel

The macro filters for different names (filter field 6) and days (filter field 20) in the sheet "**MASTER**". After filtering the sheet, it copies for example everything with "**Nils**" in filter field 6 to the sheet "**Nils**".

It thought it works, but after checking the results I noticed something I can't solve. He does not copy every row that meets the criteria (name and >-9 days).
When I take a look in the **MASTER** sheet, I can find the row the macro should have copied.

```
Sub DeleteFilterAndCopy()

Dim LASSSST As Long
Dim IP As Worksheet

Sheets("MASTER").Select

Set IP = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")

LASSSST = IP.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("MASTER").Cells.clearcontents
Sheets("hideMASTER").Range("A4:U" & LASSSST).Copy
Sheets("MASTER").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Sheets("Alex").Range("A2:T1000").clearcontents
Sheets("Anett Edith").Range("A2:T1000").clearcontents
Sheets("Angela").Range("A2:T1000").clearcontents
Sheets("Dirk").Range("A2:T1000").clearcontents
Sheets("Daniel").Range("A2:T1000").clearcontents
Sheets("Klaus").Range("A2:T1000").clearcontents
Sheets("Konrad").Range("A2:T1000").clearcontents
Sheets("Marion").Range("A2:T1000").clearcontents
Sheets("Martin").Range("A2:T1000").clearcontents
Sheets("Michael").Range("A2:T1000").clearcontents
Sheets("Mirko").Range("A2:T1000").clearcontents
Sheets("Nils").Range("A2:T1000").clearcontents
Sheets("Ulrike").Range("A2:T1000").clearcontents

Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim AlexSheet As Worksheet, AnettEdithSheet As Worksheet, AngelaShett As Worksheet, DanielSheet As Worksheet
Dim DirkSheet As Worksheet, KlausSheet As Worksheet, Konradsheet As Worksheet
Dim MarionSheet As Worksheet, MartinSheet As Worksheet, MichaelSheet As Worksheet, MirkoSheet As Worksheet
Dim NilsSheet As Worksheet, Ulrikesheet As Worksheet

Set AlexSheet = Sheets("Alex")
Set AnettEdithSheet = Sheets("Anett Edith")
Set AngelaSheet = Sheets("Angela")
Set DanielSheet = Sheets("Daniel")
Set DirkSheet = Sheets("Dirk")
Set KlausSheet = Sheets("Klaus")
Set Konradsheet = Sheets("Konrad")
Set MarionSheet = Sheets("Marion")
Set MartinSheet = Sheets("Martin")
Set MichaelSheet = Sheets("Michael")
Set MirkoSheet = Sheets("Mirko")
Set NilsSheet = Sheets("Nils")
Set Ulrikesheet = Sheets("Ulrike")

lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER")
.Range("T4").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("T4"), order1:=xlDescending, _
        Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End With


With Range("B1:U" & lngLastRow)
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Alexandra"
    .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=">=-9"
    .Copy AlexSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Anett / Edith"
    .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=">=-9"
    .Copy AnettEdithSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Angela"
    .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=">=-9"
    .Copy AngelaSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Daniel"
    .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=">=-9"
    .Copy DanielSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Dirk"
    .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=">=-9"
    .Copy DirkSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Klaus"
    .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=">=-9"
    .Copy KlausSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Konrad"
    .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=">=-9"
    .Copy Konradsheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Marion"
    .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=">=-9"
    .Copy MarionSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Martin"
    .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=">=-9"
    .Copy MartinSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Michael"
    .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=">=-9"
    .Copy MichaelSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Mirko"
    .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=">=-9"
    .Copy MirkoSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Nils"
    .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=">=-9"
    .Copy NilsSheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Ulrike"
    .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=">=-9"
    .Copy Ulrikesheet.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter
End With

Sheets("INPUT").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Could it be some type of calculation restriction? It's about 1000 rows that the macro has to filter and copy into 13 different sheets.

Comment: do you have other sheets in your workbook except the list you provided, "MASTER" and "hideMASTER" ? if you don't you can save a lot of rows and Use a total different approach (there's no need to define worksheet object per sheet, and then filter each one in 3 different rows

Comment: Yes I have another sheet. hideMASTER only converts the content via excel formulas.

Comment: this line `lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row` are you trying to find the last row ? in which worksheet ?

Comment: This is one code line I forgot, after changing something. Thanks! I'll remove it and replace it with LASSSST.

Comment: I'll write a piece of code below, it's not the answer, but it's a more elegant way of writing what you have coded here

Comment: Its important for me that I can run the macro from a different sheet. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the full answer, just a shorter, "cleaner" and more versatile way.
See my comments inside the code, some are questions

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteFilterAndCopy()

Dim LASSSST                     As Long
Dim IP                          As Worksheet
Dim Sht                         As Worksheet
Dim ShtNamesArr                 As Variant
Dim i                           As Long

' put all your desired sheet names into array
ShtNamesArr = Array("Alex", "Anett Edith", "Angela", "Dirk", "Daniel", "Klaus", "Konrad", "Marion", "Martin", "Michael", "Mirko", "Nils", "Ulrike")

Set IP = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")

' get last row in Column B fron sheet "Input"
LASSSST = IP.Cells(IP.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("MASTER").Cells.ClearContents

' using Last row from sheet "Input" and use it in sheet "hideMASTER" ???
Sheets("hideMASTER").Range("A4:U" & LASSSST).Copy
Sheets("MASTER").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

' Method 1 of clearing contents in Range A2:T1000 in all specific sheets
For i = LBound(ShtNamesArr) To UBound(ShtNamesArr)
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(ShtNamesArr(i)).Range("A2:T1000").ClearContents  ' this method might return an error if sheet name not found
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i

' Method 2 of clearing contents in Range A2:T1000 in all specific sheets
For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Select Case Sht.Name
        Case "Alex", "Anett Edith", "Angela", "Dirk", "Daniel", "Klaus", "Konrad", "Marion", "Martin", "Michael", "Mirko", "Nils", "Ulrike"
            Sht.Range("A2:T1000").ClearContents
    End Select
Next Sht

Dim lngLastRow                  As Long

' which sheet is this suppose to be ???
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER")
    .Range("T4").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("T4"), order1:=xlDescending, _
        Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End With

With Range("B1:U" & lngLastRow)
    .AutoFilter

    ' lppo through all sheet names array elements, and per each element filter the table and copy it to the relevant sheet
    For i = LBound(ShtNamesArr) To UBound(ShtNamesArr)
        .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=ShtNamesArr(i)
        .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=">=-9"
        .Copy Sheets(ShtNamesArr(i)).Range("A1")
    Next i
End With


Sheets("INPUT").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! but it clears the sheet MASTER instead of all other sheets.

Comment: are you sure ? did you copy the entire code here ? I just tested again on my PC and it's working fine. You are clearing sheet "MASTER" in your code, you have the line `Sheets("MASTER").Cells.clearcontents` I just copied it here

Comment: Yes but it does not copy the content from hideMASTER. I know you coded the but it does not work somehow...

Comment: did you read my comments in my code ? you are setting `LASSSST` fromsheet "Input" , but using it on sheet "hideMASTER" ??

Comment: Input and hideMASTER have the same amount of rows.

Comment: you can see that part of the code is the same as yours, I just reduced all the code aftewards